# Why Api Route is not working in laravel application, Showing Error (not Found 404 error)?

Tags: laravel, api, model-view-controller, routes, http-status-code-404

Api Route is Not Working .
Web and Admin Route Working Properly.
We Checked RouteServiceProvider.php

```html
protected function mapApiRoutes()
  {
    Route::prefix('api')
       ->middleware('api')
       ->namespace($this->namespace)
       ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing route cache?

Comment: show us a URL example?

Comment: Are you seeing any sort of error message. Can you include the actual routes/api.php file and what url you are going to in the browser

Comment: Have you tried multiple routes, errors like ModelNotFound can also trigger 404 errors, depending on how the handler it used it can be camouflaged.

Comment: i tried after cache clear. still same issue

Answer (score 0):

With Laravel 8 you can do:

In the **boot** method on your **AppServiceProvider** add **$this->routes()**

```
public function boot()
{
   $this->routes(function () {
     Route::prefix('api')
       ->middleware('api')
       ->namespace($this->namespace)
       ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
   }
}
```

An example **api.php** file could be:

```
Route::get('/user', UserController::class, 'index');
Route::post('/user', UserController::class, 'register');
```

Those routes should be prefixed with **/api/**, example: **/api/user**.

Good luck :)

Comment: i tried after cache clear. still same issue. also i tried simple rout in api.php Route::get('tttt', function(){
    echo 78;
});